# How do I make the button size the same width regardless of the content length in LWC?

Tags: lightning-web-components, custom-button, button, ui

I have written up some code in [Playground](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/X9NBKjLs/2/edit) but isn't working as I expected.

I want to make the buttons in LWC the same size as in picture below (which in turn will naturally make the spacing the same) :

[image]

How do I go about achieving this? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1):

As you are working with divs, that  could be achieved with css grid layout. Please find below the best guide I found about it.

[CSS Grid Guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/)

CSS Grid also gives a very good responsive result, and it is always a good option in terms of layouts.

Every div you have will be dropped into a cell of your css grid, but you first must specify the columns and rows you want for it.

Comment: hmm .. I highly doubt can use CSS on <lightning-button>

Comment: You do not apply the grid to the buttons, but to the container.

Comment: Hi! Did this make it for you to solve your problem?

Comment: No it didn't. How does editing the container make the button the same size?

Comment: CSS Grid lets you create a layout in which you control the content. Haven't tried but I'd say that if your columns are limited to i.e. 100 px, and your button is 100% width, it will adjust to its container.

Comment: Also, it lets you control the space between columns and rows like you mentioned (property 'gap'), and it's fully responsive. If I had to create what you are trying to, I would definitely go for CSS grid layout instead of relying on the natural flow of the doc.